# Truncate multiple tables after finding those tables using a select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to truncate tables I find,  all in 1 script.  I have the select criteria now I need to truncate these tables. 1 problem I have is it can be different tables every time I run the query.

```sql
   SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TruncateCommands VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @TruncateCommands = STUFF((
    SELECT ';' + char(13) + char(10) + 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)
    FROM 
   (
     SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName], [Tables].name AS 
     [TableName], SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
    FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
    JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
    ON [Tables].[onject_id]= [Partitions].[object_id]
    AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
    WHERE EXISTS
       ( 
        SELECT * FROM sys.columns
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID([Table].name)
        AND sys.columns.Name = 'CreatedOn'
        and [Tables].name not like '%Bck%'
        and [Tables].name not like '%Bk_%'
        and [Tables].name not like '%Bak_%'
        )
       AND EXISTS
          (
            SELECT * FROM 
             sys.columns tS
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID ([Tables].name)
            AND
              (
               tS.Name like '%mrn%'
                    or tS.Name = 'cfk_hr'
                    or tS.Name like '%pt%name%'
                    or tS.Name like '%scriptext%'
                    or tS.Name like '%F%name%'
                    or tS.Name like '%L%name%'
                    or tS.Name like '%patient%'
                    or tS.Name like '%address%'
                    or tS.Name like '%phone%'
                    or tS.Name like '%email%' 
                    or tS.Name like '%ssn%'
                    or tS.Name like '%dob%'
                    or tS.Name like '%dob%'
                    or tS.Name like '%sex%'
                    or tS.Name like '%fax%'
                    or tS.Name like '%NPI%'
                    or tS.Name like '%DEA%'
                    )
                 )
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value ('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
PRINT @TruncateCommands
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of generating dynamic SQL to build the `Truncate` commands.  My example was run against the `AdventureWorks` database looking for tables that began with `Sales%`.  Replace with your selection criteria.  The `Truncate` commands are concatenated into a varchar string variable.  The `PRINT` command shows you the generated SQL.  Un-comment the `exec sp_executesql @TruncateCommands` to actual run the `Truncate` commands.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TruncateCommands VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @TruncateCommands = STUFF((
    SELECT ';' + char(13) + char(10) + 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)
    FROM 
    (   --your selection query here
    select schema_name(schema_id) as SchemaName,object_name(object_id) as TableName
    from sys.Tables
    where name like 'sales%'
    ) t
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

PRINT @TruncateCommands
--exec sp_executesql @TruncateCommands  --uncomment to execute truncate commands
```

---

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesPerson];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesPersonQuotaHistory];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesReason];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesTaxRate];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesTerritory];
TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales].[SalesTerritoryHistory]
```

---

I took the *original* query you posted (by looking back at the history of the question) and pasted in my example.  I had to make a few changes because you had some syntax problems.  I don't get any results on my computer because I don't have any objects that use your table and column names, but the query completes without any errors.  Here is what I used:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TruncateCommands VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @TruncateCommands = STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName]
                        ,[Tables].NAME AS [TableName]
                        ,SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
                    FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
                    JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
                        ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
                            AND [Partitions].index_id IN (
                                0
                                ,1
                                )
                    WHERE EXISTS (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM sys.columns
                            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID([Tables].NAME)
                                AND sys.columns.NAME = 'CreatedOn'
                                AND [Tables].NAME NOT LIKE '%Bck%'
                                AND [Tables].NAME NOT LIKE '%Bk_%'
                                AND [Tables].NAME NOT LIKE '%Bak_%'
                            )
                        AND EXISTS (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM sys.columns tS
                            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID([Tables].NAME)
                                AND (
                                    tS.NAME LIKE '%mrn%'
                                    OR tS.NAME = 'cfk_hr'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%pt%name%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%scriptext%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%F%name%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%L%name%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%patient%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%address%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%phone%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%email%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%ssn%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%dob%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%dob%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%sex%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%fax%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%NPI%'
                                    OR tS.NAME LIKE '%DEA%'
                                    )
                            )
                    GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)
                        ,[Tables].NAME
                    ) d
                WHERE totalrowcount > 1
                ) t
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @TruncateCommands
```

---

Does this updated query give you the results you are after?

Comment: I've added my search criteria but i'm getting a syntax error at the FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value

Comment: @TonyOtero - can you update your question with your latest query attempt?  It's difficult to _guess_ on what your problem might be.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated it.  I appreciate your help.